# Adding a semicircle in center on top of Jumbotron

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to achieve this design having a semicircle with logo inside in the center. Kindly refer to the link given below.

[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5zEQG.png)

I have tried making a semicircle using CSS but it won't be suitable for the design that I want. I have used 2 jumbotrons, one after the other. The semicircle should cover the area on both jumbotron as in the image(link mentioned above).
Any help is appreciated on how can I achieve this design.

HTML:

```
<div class="jumbotron">
    <div class="container navheader">
    <div class="social">
        <a href=""><i class="fa fa-facebook " aria-hidden="true"></i></a>
        <a href=""><i class="fa fa-google-plus " aria-hidden="true"></i></a>
        <a href=""><i class="fa fa-instagram " aria-hidden="true"></i></a>
    </div>
    <div class="contact-us">
        <a href="">
            <i class="fa fa-phone " aria-hidden="true">&nbsp;
        <label class="icon-label">CALL 0417 949 773</label></i></a>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="jumbotron other-color">
    <div class="container navheader">
        <div class="user-actions">
            <button class="btn btn-link" data-toggle="modal" data-
               target="#sign-in">
                <i class="fa fa-lock" aria-hidden="true">&nbsp;
                    <label class="icon-label">SIGN IN</label>
                </i>
            </button>
            <button class="btn btn-link" data-toggle="modal" data-
            target="#sign-up">
                <i class="fa fa-user " aria-hidden="true">&nbsp;
                    <label class="icon-label">CREATE AN ACCOUNT</label>
                </i>
            </button>
    </div>
    <div class="div-semicircle top"></div>
        <div class="cart">
            <a href=""><i class="fa fa-shopping-cart " aria-
             hidden="true">&nbsp;
                <label class="icon-label">2 ITEM(S)</label>
            </i></a>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
<style>
        /* Remove the navbar's default rounded borders and increase the bottom margin */ 
        .navbar {
            margin-bottom: 50px;
            border-radius: 0;
        }

        /* Remove the jumbotron's default bottom margin */ 
        .jumbotron {
            margin-bottom: 0;
            background-color: #5a9f33;
            padding: 2em 1em;
        }
        .other-color {
            margin-bottom; 0; 
            background-color: #67b63d;
            padding: 2em 1em;
        }
        .navheader{
            display: inline-block; 
            width: 100%;
        }
        .social, .user-actions{
            float:left;
        }
        .contact-us, .cart{
            float:right;
        }
        .sign-up{
            background-color:#67b63d;
            margin: 0 50px 50px;
            padding:20px;
        }
        input{
            padding:15px;
            margin:20px;
            width:85%;
        }
        .btn-sign{
            background-color: #67b63d;
            font-family: serif;
            color: white;
            border-radius: 30px;
            font-size: 2em;
            padding: 10px 50px;
            margin: 20px auto;
            display: block;
        }
        .title{
            font-family: serif;
            font-weight: 600;
            color: #67b63d;
            font-size: 3em;
            margin-top:20px;
        }
        .div-semicircle {
            background: #9e978e;
            display: inline-block;
            margin: 0 1em 1em 0;
        }
        .top,
        .bottom {
            height: 45px;
            width: 90px;
        }
        .top {
            border-top-left-radius: 90px ;
            border-top-right-radius: 90px;
        }

    </style>
```

***UPDATE:***
Solution: In case anyone wants to know, refer to the sample by @bhv in the first comment for reference and tweak it as per your requirement.

Comment: [demo](https://jsfiddle.net/3n1ch1n1/)  a sample, not the answer

Comment: @bhv Thanks mate. The sample was helpful.

Answer (score 0):

first of all your posted code isn't of any help....still I'll try to give a procedure how you can achieve the linked image

1. create a div **not with class .container**
2. create 2 navs inside above created div
3. create a jumbotron below the navs inside the same div and contain it
   in a **div with class container**
4. set margins as you need it between these 3 to bring them together
5. It is clearly visible that **you dont need a semicircle**..**you need an ellipse use** `clip-path: ellipse(65px 30px at 125px 40px);` someting like this to create it **within same div** then position it in a way you want to using css and give it highest z-index so that it renders as top-most layer.
6. prey that it works!! ;-)

Comment: Thanks for helping. The sample mentioned by @bhv in First comment was helpful in getting the required design. And yes it is an ellipse not a semicircle. Thanks for correcting.

Answer (score 0):

you must use position:absolute to cover both jumbotron
add these lines of code to this class: .div-semicircle.

```
    position: absolute;
    top: 23%;
    left: 40%;
```